# Store a delegate method as a member of class

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm doing coded ui testing, basically unit testing for the ui, and I have created a `TestObject` class that stores a list of assertions to be performed against itself within the TestMethod that instantiates it.

```
public class TestObject {
    public string urlToTest;
    public List<Assertion> assertions;
}

public class Assertion {
    public List<SearchPropertyExpression> searchPropertyExpressions;
    public Action assertMethod;
    public string expectedValue; // <-- this works fine if I'll always call a method like AreEqual() where it has an expected value, but what if I want to store a method in assertMethod that has different arguments???
}

public class SearchPropertyExpression {
    public string expression;
    public string value;
}
```

I would like to store the assert method (for example: `Assert.AreEqaul(object expected, object actual)` that I want executed against that particular `TestObject` and call that later but I'm struggling to get something that is syntactically correct. I'm also struggling with how to pass the arguments for that delegate method (`assertMethod`) when it's actually called. All methods that I'll be calling are within `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert`. In the example below I would like to call `Assert.AreEqaul()` but any method with varying arguments could be called. Here's what I've got so far...

```
[TestMethod]
public void uiTestConnectionsEducationHomePage() {
    //instantiate test object
    TestObject testObject = new TestObject() {
        urlToTest = "/example/home.aspx",
        assertions = {
            new Assertion() {
                searchPropertyExpressions = {
                    new SearchPropertyExpression() {
                        expression = HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id,
                        value = "header"
                    }
                },
                assertMethod = Assert.AreEqual // <-- this is wrong,I'm thinking I need to tell assertMethod what arguments to expect here, lambda??
            }
        }
    };

    // get handle to browser and launch
    UiBrowserWindow uiBrowserWindow = new UiBrowserWindow();
    uiBrowserWindow.launchUrl(testObject.urlToTest);

    // assertions
    testObject.assertions.ForEach(x => {
        HtmlDiv htmlObject = new HtmlDiv();
        x.searchPropertyExpressions.ForEach(p => {
            htmlObject = uiBrowserWindow.uiHtmlDocument.searchHtmlElementByAttributeValue<HtmlDiv>(p.expression, p.value);
        });
        x.assertMethod; // <-- for this is example the arguments would be (htmlObject, "header").                   
    });
}
```

I think my real problem is that there is a design pattern here that could really help me but I'm not well versed in design patterns.

Comment: Do you own the class that you wish to store the method in?  It doesn't look like it but I thought I would check to be sure.

Comment: ok then this is easy I think I will give you a small demo, just give me a moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `assertMethod` delegate is of type `Action` which represents a method with a return type of void and no parameters, e.g. `void Foo()`.
`Assert.AreEqual` has [many overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the most universial being `Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual)`. I suggest you use this and change your delegate accordingly:

```
Action<Object, Object> assertMethod;
```

Comment: thanks Daniel. Something just hit me, since I could be passing any Assert method with possibly different arguments for each method call, how do I dynamically call assertMethod within my TestMethod so that the proper arguments are passed to each Assert method?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this if you want your delegate to point to any method definition:-

```
public delegate void MyAction(params object[] args);
public class Assertion
{
    public List<PropertyExpression> propertyExpressions;
    public MyAction assertMethod;
}
public void Test()
{
   var asser = new Assertion()
                    {
                        assertMethod = (vals) =>Assert.AreEqual(vals[0],vals[1]);
                        propertyExpressions = null
                    };
   var asser2 = new Assertion()
                    {
                        assertMethod = (vals)=>Assert.AreEqual((string)vals[0],(string)vals[1],(bool)vals[2]);
                        propertyExpressions = null
                    };

    asser.assertMethod(1, 1);//calling object,object overload
    asser2.assertMethod("ab", "cd", true);//calling string,string,bool overload
}
```

Comment: thanks BuggyCoder. The problem is that I still need to pass arguments when the delegate is actually called, and since I won't know what method is actually being called at runtime I can't pass arguments when the delegate is called. Does that make any sense? I think I would need to specify the arguments when the `TestObject` is instantiated, I think???

Comment: See we are passing arguments only when assertMethod is called, at the time of building the delegate(MyAction) we are building the AreEquals using Lambda... The arguments that you see in lambda are just to tell assertmethod that what its definition/body will look like..

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong angle. I'm currently looping through all the assertion objects in `TestObject` and trying to execute the assertion method in each Assertion object. The problem is that there's no way of knowing (at least I think there isn't) what the arguments are when `assertMethod`is actually called.

Comment: I made changes to my code above, see the comment at `x.assertMethod` near the bottom of the code